# iOS 15 simulator scrolling artifact bug in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-simulator, ios15

I updated my OS Xcode to iOS 15 and I'm getting this artifact when scrolling. Before the update everything scrolled fine. **What's odd is when I go to the Home Screen I see similar artifacts when moving apps around (the tops get cut off).**

OS: 11.6 (20G165)
Xcode: 13.0 (13A233)
Hardware: MBP15 2017

What I tried:

- clean
- clearing cache in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
- A different simulator
- iOS 14.5 simulator
- Deleting app

It seems to be a larger problem than just my app. Does anyone know of a workaround?

[image: Gif]

Snippet of code:

```
 //
//  ContentView.swift
//  ForElTomato
//
//  Created by Ran on 9/30/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let colors:[Color] = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green]
    let names:[String] = ["El", "Tomato", "The Best"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true, content: {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [], content: {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { clr in
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                        LazyHStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [], content: {
                            ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                                        Button(action: {
                                            //nothing
                                        }) {
                                            HStack {
                                                Text(name)
                                            }.padding(10)
                                        }.foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .background(clr)
                                            .animation(.default)
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }.padding(.leading)
            })
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do guys named 'vm' and 'colorScheme' come from?  Your code is way off Clean Architecture.  Nobody can reproduce your work.

Comment: @ElTomato updated the code. Also updated the gif so that you can see the Home Screen also clips.

Comment: Hmm...  If I run your code with an iPod touch 7th gen. simulator running iOS 15.0, I don't see the problem you are reporting.

Comment: I see.  I see the same problem if I run it with iPhone 13 mini simulator.  If I replace the first ScrollView guy with List, removing the first second ScrollView, I don't see the problem, except that that's not what you want, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for checking iPod touch. I think I'll go with that. Thanks again!

Comment: I also experience this issue with iOS 15. Before an update everything was smooth and fine. iPod touch is fine too.